# Find the biggest sum out of the all, it containing numbers and

Tags: c++, for-loop

*I need to find **the biggest sum** and **it containing numbers** and **whether the first or second number out of two was bigger**.* How to find it?

Let's say that n=10, the two put numbers are 6 and 2, followings: 7 and 1,
5 and 6, 1 and 8, 4 and 3. Then the answer should be that the biggest sum is 11, it containing numbers are 5 and 6, and the bigger numb was the second one.

I have a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


int p, a, i;
int n;
int sum;

ofstream fr("Rezults.txt");
ifstream fd("Data.txt");
fd>>n;

cout<<n<<endl;





for (i=1; i<=n/2; i++)
{
    fd>>p>>a;
    sum=p+a;
    for (int j=sum; j<=n/2; j++);
    {
            cout<<sum<<endl;

    }

}


fd.close();

fr<<sum;

fr.close();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BrianGradin the question is how to find the biggest sum and it containing numbers and whether the first or second number out of two was bigger.

Comment: That's not a valid English sentence.  I still doesn't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @BrianGradin Let's say we have ten cards. We play a game. We write on the cards numbers from one to ten. Then one of us puts one card, another puts another card so we have two cards in the line. The first line contains numbers 6 and 2, and others as I mentioned above... Then the questions are: how to find the biggest sum of the two numbers in one line? And it containing numbers as well as if the bigger number was the first one in the line or the second one?

Comment: What do you mean by "And it containing numbers"?  That makes no sense.

Comment: @BrianGradin sorry for my pure English! If the numbers are two and six it is what the sum contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


int p, a, i;
int n;
int sum;

ofstream fr("Rezults.txt");
ifstream fd("Data.txt");
fd>>n;

cout<<n<<endl;



fd>>p>>a;
int biggestSum=p+a;
int first = p;
int second = a;
for (i=2; i<=n/2; i++)
{
    fd>>p>>a;
    sum=p+a;
    if(sum > biggestSum)
    {
        biggestSum = sum;
        first = p;
        second = a;
    }

}

cout <<"biggest sum is "<<biggestSum<<"\n";
cout <<"The first number is "<<first<<"\n";
cout<<"The second number is "<<second<<"\n";

fd.close();

fr<<sum;

fr.close();


return 0;
}
```

updated : you should be careful to the index i of the for loop it should start by 2 since you read the first two numbers before the for loop.